# Use URI.js with Firefox Addon SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm attempting to use URI.js with the Firefox Addon SDK.

I've include the URI.js file (built from https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/build.html) in my Addon SDK index.js file - but I keep getting the following error:

> Module `./punycode` is not found at resource://uw-cashback-wizard/punycode.js

As a workaround, I thought I might use a worker, but workers only allow async messaging, and I'm trying to use it as part of synchronous methods.

Comment: Do you want to use this inside a `contentScript` or in your `main.js`/`index.js`. Async shouldn't be a limitation, you can always block if you really have to do sync, if you can ever do it from a worker, you should without question.